# How to create a splash screen or progress loading bar in Ember web app

Tags: ember.js, splash-screen

As an example:

http://help.apple.com/numbers/mac/3.6/

If you visit this page, you see first the activity indicator, then the page loads up. It feels like splash screen. The site seems built in Ember.js 1.x. I like the idea to have such splash screen, better than nothing especially when the network speed is slow.

How to implement this feature in Ember? Any good addon?

Comment: just use a simple CSS spinner in your plain HTML *before* you load the ember app, and remove it after ember is ready.

Comment: How do I know Ember is ready?

Comment: [Use the `ready` event](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Application.html#event_ready)

Answer (score 4):

Use the application loading substate, you can generate a template with

```
ember g template application-loading
```

(note the dash)

You can find out more about substates here:

https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.4.0/routing/loading-and-error-substates/

Or watch Alex short talk about them:

https://vimeo.com/157235004

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the [Pace](https://github.com/vectart/ember-cli-pace) library that can show spin bar also on loading initial scripts